# Input query for python code

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm

So I have created this code for my research, but I want to use it for plenty of data files, I do not want to do it manually, which means retyping some lines in my code to use desired file. How to use `input` command in python (I work with python 2.7 on Windows OS) to use it faster, just by typing name of desired datafile. My code so far:

```
import iodata as io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time
from scipy.signal import welch
from scipy import signal

testInstance = io.InputConverter()
start = time.time()
conversionError = io.ConversionError()
#data = testInstance.convert(r"S:\Doktorat\Python\", 1", conversionError)
data = testInstance.convert(r"/Users/PycharmProjects/Hugo/20160401", "201604010000", conversionError)
end = time.time()
print("time elapsed " + str(end - start))

if(conversionError.conversionSucces):
    print("Conversion succesful")
if(conversionError.conversionSucces == False):
    print("Conversion failed: " + conversionError.conversionErrorLog)
print "Done!"

# Create a new subplot for two cannals 1 & 3
a = np.amin(data.data)
Bx = data.data[0,]
By = data.data[1,]
dt = float(300)/266350
Fs = 1/dt
t = np.arange(0,300,dt*1e3)
N = len(Bx)
M = len(By)
time = np.linspace(0,300,N)
time2 = np.linspace(0,300,M)

filename = 'C:/Users/PycharmProjects/Hugo/20160401/201604010000.dat'
d = open(filename,'rb')
degree = u"\u00b0"
headersize = 64
header = d.read(headersize)
ax1 = plt.subplot(211)
ax1.set_title(header[:16] + ', ' +                                  # station name
    'Canals: '+header[32:33]+' and '+header[34:35]+ ', '            # canals
    +'Temp'+header[38:43]+degree+'C'                                # temperature
    +', '+'Time:'+header[26:32]+', '+'Date'+' '+header[16:26])      # date

plt.ylabel('Pico Tesle [pT]')
plt.xlabel('Time [ms]')
plt.grid()
plt.plot(time[51:-14], Bx[51:-14], label='Canal 1', color='r', linewidth=0.1, linestyle="-")
plt.plot(time2[1:-14], By[1:-14], label='Canal 3', color='b', linewidth=0.1, linestyle="-")
plt.legend(loc='upper right', frameon=False, )

# Create a new subplot for FFT
plt.subplot(212)
plt.title('Fast Fourier Transform')
plt.ylabel('Power [a.u.]')
plt.xlabel('Frequency Hz')
xaxis2 = np.arange(0,470,10)
plt.xticks(xaxis2)
fft1 = (Bx[51:-14])
fft2 = (By[1:-14])
plt.grid()

# Loop for FFT data
for dataset in [fft1]:
    dataset = np.asarray(dataset)
    freqs, psd = welch(dataset, fs=266336/300, window='hamming', nperseg=8192)
    plt.semilogy(freqs, psd/dataset.size**0, color='r')

for dataset2 in [fft2]:
    dataset2 = np.asarray(dataset2)
    freqs2, psd2 = welch(dataset2, fs=266336/300, window='hamming', nperseg=8192)
    plt.semilogy(freqs2, psd2/dataset2.size**0, color='b')
plt.show()
```

As you can see there are some places where it would be better to put `input` and when I run the code I can write names of filenames etc. to python instead of creating every single pythonfile, with specified info in the code. 
Btw. I use Pycharm to my python.

Comment: So you just want `filename` to not be hardcoded?

Comment: @ Carcigenicate I think my question was not too specific. Look, I have data from measuring stations, here is "Hugo". And from those stations I have plenty of measurements, saved in files. What I need is to run my code, and just type in input command e.g. File: Hugo, Measurement: 201604010000 and run it.

Comment: Welcome to the community. If an answer has helped you solve your problem, you should accept it. See [How does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you are trying to do is get rid of the hardcoded pathname, you should be able to format your name string with input variables

```
name = raw_input("Name: ")
measurement = raw_input("Measurement: ")
filename =  "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/{0}/{1}".format(name, measurement)
```

see [raw_input](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#raw_input) and [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)